# Cordova IOS 8 select element

Tags: html, ios, cordova, ios8

I've recently upgraded Cordova to 3.6.3 and Xcode to 6. I've noticed when testing on iOS that select elements no longer do anything when clicked. This works in iOS 7.0/7.1 but fails on all emulators once I move to iOS 8.

Is this a known bug and is there a fix currently available?

```
<div>
    <select id="task" style="height: 32px; text-align:left">
        <option>Other</option>
        <option>Mining</option>
        <option SELECTED>Farming</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Thanks, 
Michael

Comment: I found the solution to this. This is a bug with the ios-sim. On a device running 8.XX the select element does work as expected. Hopefully there will be an update to the ios-sim to fix this in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with the ios 8 simulator. Unchecked Hardware>Keyboard>Connect hardware keyboard and the issue is solved!

Answer (score 1):

robiso in the Apple forum figured it out:

I had the same issue with the ios 8 simulator. Unchecked Hardware>Keyboard>Connect hardware keyboard and the issue is solved!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue of HTML select elements not functioning in PhoneGap apps (and also native UIWebView apps) on 8.0.2 DEVICES.  I think this is more than a simulator issue.

MikeH:  are you using some kind of CSS property to get selector elements to pop open the option picker on your 8.xx device?  Mine just bring up the next /back arrows and the "done" button.

Comment: I have been working with CSS to open the select elements which fail on iOS 8 simulator. As mentioned above though that trick fixed it for me.